# How to get correct code coverage using GCOV? As it keeps on showing 0% covered

Tags: c++, gcc, gcov

I am trying to get code coverage on subset of a massive codebase, currently experimenting with **gcov**.

- Having compiled subset of code base with following compile flags **-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage** and **-lgcov** link flag. All the *.gcno* files are created.
- Now when I run the code file suppose *A.cpp* (not directly through terminal but functions of that file are called through some other file ) I see some uncertain behavior with *.gcda* file.
- It doesn't get updated on every run (checked the stat for *.gcda* file), but does get updated in some runs. 
  Once I run gcov it gives **0% coverage** for **A.cpp** as well as all other *.cpp* files.
- I have verified that the script do run as there are results obtained that are only possible by functions provided in the *A.cpp*.

Have checked the version of **gcov** and **gcc**, I am using **gcc** version **8.3.1**, and don't see any version mismatch. I have tried running gcov on a small test script factorial.cpp and it shows correct coverage on it.

Expecting some kind of code coverage on subset code base.

Comment: Can you try running this using geninfo with the -b flag which specifies the directory to be used for source files.

Comment: I tried running it on one file it didn't throw error. But gave answer like below 
DA: XX,0
DA:XY,0 all of them say's 0 in my case.